# Drawing Power From USB Type B Port

Tags: usb, usb-host

Can you draw power from a USB Type B port?

I have a raspberry pi connected to a printer from its type A port to the printer's type B port. The raspberry pi also has a type C port to provide it power. I'm wondering if I could put in some kind of dongle where the computer could send data to the printer while also drawing its power from the same port.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A USB type B port is data and power in only

It was never designed to provide power